# Selenium web driver stops working while constantly refreshing but doens't time out

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.get("x.com")
#Wait till page is loaded
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("-"))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out.")
finally:
```

I have a loop that runs this code over and over, getting a new page every couple seconds. It seems after it runs about 7 times it stops wokring as the webdriverwait command doesn't detect the title. However, I dont seem to get the timed out error. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

By default, selenium wait for the request before firing the next action. E.g.

```
driver.get("www.x.com") 
driver.findElement("something").click // this action will not trigger until the first action is fired.
```

Comment: I'm aware. However, my request is basically timing out but my exception error isn't catching it so it just sits there doing nothing until I terminate the program.